# How to make data Sync from AWS RDS to another AWS RDS with different schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, data-synchronization, amazon-rds, mysqlbinlog

I have Mysql RDS1 and another Mysql RDS2 where the schema is different.

I need the any changes on RDS1 to be synced immediately to Mysql RDS2.

where the data changes due to create, insert, update and delete

Both RDS1 and RDS2 is alive and integrated to diff app.

I referred: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fast-easy-free-sync-rds-to-redshift/

but still searching for a proper solution for my problem.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a RDS MySQL instance from a MySQL command line using

```
mysql -h <end_point> -P <port> -u <user_name> -p
```

and try to set up a cron job to sync the data between the servers/databases.

Also there are other GUI like https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog that lets you to connect to the RDS instances and lets you compare and sync the schema of databases spread across different servers and also sync the data either at present or scheduling it to a particular time.

Comment: Thank you marlong, i need sync immediately like pubsub.. even seconds matters. I trying with cron... Seeking for optimal way..